# Load family (and not typeface) name from font in file system

Tags: c#, fonts

I'm loading fonts from the filesystem .

generally my code works very well, but as i load the fonts through a PrivateFontCollection the name of the loaded FontFamily is the name of the TypeFace in the font (what i can see under Typeface name in the Font previewer of windows) and not the FontFamily name...

As i have some fonts which have the same Typeface name but another font name i would like to be able to distinguish between them. Anyone has a idea how to get the real FontFamily name?

```
    public Dictionary<string, FontFamily> LoadFontsFromDirectory(string path)
    {
        Dictionary<string, FontFamily> foundFonts = new Dictionary<string, FontFamily>();

        if (!Directory.Exists(path)) throw new Exception("directory doesnt exist");

        foreach(FileInfo fi in new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles("*.ttf"))
        {
            PrivateFontCollection fileFonts = new PrivateFontCollection();
            fileFonts.AddFontFile(fi.FullName);
            if (!foundFonts.ContainsKey(fileFonts.Families[0].Name))
            {
                //add the font only if this fontfamily doesnt exist yet
                FontFamily family = new FontFamily(String.Format("file:///{0}#{1}", fi.FullName, fileFonts.Families[0].Name));
                foundFonts.Add(family.Name, family);
            }
        }

        return foundFonts;
    }
```

Comment: Would this link me of any use? [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/f570b1a5-dcd9-4223-af04-be16e055a5f3/#7d95f7c3-3236-4840-ad9b-a7ff8637e577)

Comment: Sorry, I meant would that link BE of any use to you?

Comment: Actually, skip it. I should have spent more time reading the question, the link is not what you were looking for. My apologies

Comment: Do you mean that you want to distinguish between Times New Roman and Times New Roman Bold (for example)?  In this case both families are Times New Roman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the FontFamily as opposed to the value in fileFonts.Families[0].Name, you'll find it in family.FamilyNames by culture:

```
FontFamily family = new FontFamily(String.Format("file:///{0}#{1}", fi.FullName, fileFonts.Families[0].Name));
Console.WriteLine("\tFamilySource: {0}", family.Source);
foreach (var x in family.FamilyNames)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\tFamilyName: {0}", x);  // <------ HERE
}
foreach (var y in family.FamilyTypefaces)
{
    foreach (var z in y.AdjustedFaceNames)
    {                            
        Console.WriteLine("\tTypeface: {0}",z);
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
Arial
    FamilySource: file:///C:\Users\tim\Desktop\arial.ttf#Arial
    FamilyName: [en-us, Arial]
    Typeface: [en-us, Regular]
    Typeface: [en-us, Bold]
    Typeface: [en-us, Bold Oblique]
    Typeface: [en-us, Oblique]
Arial
    FamilySource: file:///C:\Users\tim\Desktop\arialbd.ttf#Arial
    FamilyName: [en-us, Arial]
    Typeface: [en-us, Bold]
    Typeface: [en-us, Bold Oblique]
Arial
    FamilySource: file:///C:\Users\tim\Desktop\arialbi.ttf#Arial
    FamilyName: [en-us, Arial]
    Typeface: [en-us, Bold Italic]
Arial
    FamilySource: file:///C:\Users\tim\Desktop\ariali.ttf#Arial
    FamilyName: [en-us, Arial]
    Typeface: [en-us, Italic]
    Typeface: [en-us, Bold Italic]
Arial Narrow
    FamilySource: file:///C:\Users\tim\Desktop\ARIALN.TTF#Arial Narrow
    FamilyName: [en-us, Arial]
    Typeface: [en-us, Condensed]
    Typeface: [en-us, Condensed Bold]
    Typeface: [en-us, Condensed Bold Oblique]
    Typeface: [en-us, Condensed Oblique]
Arial Narrow
    FamilySource: file:///C:\Users\tim\Desktop\ARIALNB.TTF#Arial Narrow
    FamilyName: [en-us, Arial]
    Typeface: [en-us, Condensed Bold]
    Typeface: [en-us, Condensed Bold Oblique]
Arial Narrow
    FamilySource: file:///C:\Users\tim\Desktop\ARIALNBI.TTF#Arial Narrow
    FamilyName: [en-us, Arial]
    Typeface: [en-us, Condensed Bold Italic]
Arial Narrow
    FamilySource: file:///C:\Users\tim\Desktop\ARIALNI.TTF#Arial Narrow
    FamilyName: [en-us, Arial]
    Typeface: [en-us, Condensed Italic]
    Typeface: [en-us, Condensed Bold Italic]
Arial Black
    FamilySource: file:///C:\Users\tim\Desktop\ariblk.ttf#Arial Black
    FamilyName: [en-us, Arial]
    Typeface: [en-us, Black]
    Typeface: [en-us, Black Oblique]
```

That said, your note that "i have some fonts which have the same Typeface name but another font name and i would like to be able to distinguish between them" suggests that FontFamily is not what you are actually looking for.